# Websocket connection doesn't close in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

It seems there is a problem while trying to close websocket connection from firefox (8.0.1).
When using Chrome, if you use WebSocket.close() the connection is closed immediately, in firefox i can wait about 30 seconds until it close the connection with error.

Any suggestions to bypass this problem in firefox?

Comment: The connection to ws://10.0.0.1:8121/chat was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: What WebSocket server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run into that error if the server doesn't support the handshake format that is sent from firefox. I've run into that error with Aleph because it didn't properly support multiple values in the Connection header of the handshake which is legitimate for firefox to do, but is also different from how Chrome behaves (only one value in the connection header).

If the client sends you a close message (opcode 0x8) the server should respond with a close message for clean shutdown. From the spec: "If an endpoint receives a Close frame and did not previously send a Close frame, the endpoint MUST send a Close frame in response." If the server is disconnecting the client for some reason, the server should send a close message. See section [5.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1) and [7.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4) of the spec.

Comment: the onOpen event is fired... so the connection is open

Comment: At what point do you get the "interrupted while the page was loading"? Is it when the page loads (as indicated) or after you try and disconnect?

Comment: Sounds like a possible server issue. Close works fine with firefox 8 for me. What WebSocket server are you using?

Comment: it's a .net c# server i built.
maybe i need to catch something in the server when the connection is close from firefox? because in chrome its working fine...